# Chef's knife ec2 plugin create server inside VPC with public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef, amazon-vpc, knife

So I'm using knife ec2 plugin to create a server, inside a VPC, and then provision it with chef-solo.

Here is my basic command:

```
    knife ec2 server create -S private-key -I ami-1234 --flavor=m1.medium --subnet xyz
```

The server is spun up properly, and has the proper VPC IP address. My problem is, I also need a public IP address. When I spin up an instance through the ec2 web console, it simply has an option for this **Automatically assign a public IP address to your instances**

I simply am unable to figure out how to do this via the knife command.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution I have used, although note that it requires a manual step and knowledge of your free elastic IP pool:

- Create one or more elastic IPs on the EC2 webconsole
- On the end of your `knife ec2 create server` command add `--associate-eip <free elastic ip address>`

Comment: Thanks for this correct answer. Additionally for those that might end up on this page, if you don't want to use an 'EIP' but just an auto-generated public IP you can include "--associate-public-ip" Then if you want to connect via the private IP and not the public (usually for security related concerns) use "--server-connect-attribute private_ip_address"